# MySQL query using AND instead of OR

Tags: mysql

How to write `AND` query instead of using `VALUE IN`?

I need to get exact results:This is master table

```
id  name value     
1   weight  120
2   height   5
3   active  true
4   age     35
```

I should get ids when (weight 120 AND height 5 AND age 35) . 
And should not get results when (weight 120 AND height 5 AND age 100)

Any Help

thanks

Comment: you are not clear what u exact want?? show your code where you use `IN` or paste your desired output

Comment: Agreed. This is about as clear as mud.

Comment: Please consider to rewrite your question more precisely.

Answer (score 0):

Easy one:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE `name` IN ('one', 'two') AND `value` BETWEEN 1 AND 2;
```

I hope I got you right.

### Update

Completly without `IN` it would look like the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE (`name` = 'one' OR `name` = 'two') AND `value` BETWEEN 1 AND 2;
```

### Update 2

If you are looking for pairs:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE (`name` = 'one' AND `value` = '1') OR (`name` = 'two' AND `value` = '2');
```

### Update 3

... and additionally active:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE ((`name` = 'one' AND `value` = '1') OR (`name` = 'two' AND `value` = '2'))
  AND `active` = true;
```

Looks like bad database design though. Maybe you can give us further insight about what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Alp OP said without using `IN`

Comment: above query will select that row also which have value 1.5( in case type is float)

Comment: @Alp ,Nope i need to find exact values for one- 1 and two-2 using 1 query if using IN this was doing OR , but need AND . thanks

Comment: @Sri: How can `name` be `'one'` *and* `'two'`? I think you need to reconsider your logic.

Comment: SELECT * FROM groups where name IN (1,3) and value IN ('One', 'Two').THis was doing OR operations

Comment: @Sri: Yes, it sort of has to. How can `value` be both `'One'` *and* `'Two'` at the same time? That makes no sense.

Comment: Are you looking for pairs like `one and 1` or `two and 2`?

Comment: @Alp, update 2 is what i am looking exactly , but how can we show records only if both are true only , should not show if any one is false . thanks

Comment: Update 3. You could use a bit more of your imagination though.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name='one' OR name='two'
```

OR try

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=1 OR id=2
```

Comment: No, i will get names in one array and value in another array . I was acheving when using IN , but need AND operation instead OR . thanks

Comment: @Sri: Why do you need `AND` instead of `OR`? (Please don't forget that "of"; its omission in the original question led to much confusion for me.) That seems like a silly requirement, potentially stemming from your idea of what the answer _should_ be.